# MySQL 'Friends' table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to create a table for 'Friends' in MySQL.

I have a 'Users' table with an attribute of 'user_id' which is the table's primary key.

I would like a friendship table which allows a user to add another user as a friend. However that user will remain an acquaintance to the new friend.

So for example, USER_A connects with USER_B and USER_B is now a friend of USER_A, however USER_B does not see USER_A as a friend and thus USER_A is still only an acquaintance of USER_B.

Comment: Just add 2 rows: `userA | userB` and `userB | userA`

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: So far I have thought of having user_id, friend_id and date_started as a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

You can model your table 'Friends' with 2 columns like this (pseudo code):

```
Friends(from, to)
PrimaryKey(from, to)
```

In real mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE Friends (from INT,
                      to INT,
                      PRIMARY KEY(from, to))
```

Assuming that you have an Users table with an integer as primary key.

Then, if you insert from = USER_A and to = USER_B, your intended semantic is already respected.
Because you can also add another row having from = USER_B and to = USER_A.

Comment: I am really confused by this! Two primary keys?

Comment: No. It is a primary key composed by 2 columns. A primary key can be composed by more than 1 column. Note that I wrote the example in pseudo code, you should google to check the correct syntax for such primary key.

Comment: Okay, and what would be the purpose of combining two columns for the primary key?

Comment: For example if you have a table Sales(productId, shop) for modeling products sold in different shops (and you want them to have the same id because they are the same object in the company database) you could set a primary key(productId, shop) for the table Sales (because the same product is potentially sold in more shops). It just that a lot of cases where you can not model everything with a single primary key exist.

Comment: In your case it is useful because you can have multiple rows having the same value for 'from' as long as 'to' is different.